# Activity crashes after intergrating Startapp in it

Tags: android, android-activity, sdk, crash, startapp

App crashes on button click after adding this line, there are 3 modes of this app "Easy, Medium and Hard". before i add this line (next to next 2nd code below) i could choose another mode after choosing the a mode at start then go back. but after adding this line, app crashes when i choose a game mode 2nd time(no problem at first choose)

```
StartAppSDK.init(this, "*MY APP ID", true);
```

next to

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Full Activity Code is

```
package com.myapps.app;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.myapps.app.diamen.Dimension;
import com.startapp.android.publish.StartAppSDK;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

public class PuzzleActivity extends Activity {

public static final int DIALOG_PAUSED_ID = 44;

GameBoard board;
int screenOrientation;
Bitmap sourceImage;
Button preview, back;
ViewSwitcher inGameViewSwitcher;
Typeface custom_font;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StartAppSDK.init(this, "209057502", true);

    custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.otf");
    /*preview = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previewButton);
    preview.setTypeface(custom_font);
    back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.backToGameButton);
    back.setTypeface(custom_font);*/
    // Prepare the Interstitial Ad

    screenOrientation = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainMenuActivity.EXTRA_BOARD_ORIENTATION, 1);

//        String str = screenOrientation == 0 ? "PORTRAIT" : "HORIZONTAL";
//        Log.d("KAMIL", "Orientation recorded by puzzleactivity: " + str);

    //locking the app in needed position
    if(screenOrientation == GameBoard.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    else
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    //making the app full screen
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.puzzle);

    //Setting backgrounds to black.
    ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.centerLayout)).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.backgroundLayout)).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    inGameViewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.inGameViewSwitcher);


    //Crating a game board.
    board = new GameBoard(decodeGameSizeFromIntent(),
            (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.centerLayout), 
            screenOrientation, this);

    sourceImage = loadBitmapFromIntent();

    ImageView preview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.previewImageView);
    preview.setImageBitmap(sourceImage);

    PuzzleCreator creator = new PuzzleCreator(sourceImage, board);
    board.loadTiles(creator.createPuzzle());
    board.drawBoard();
}

private Dimension decodeGameSizeFromIntent(){

    Dimension size = null;

    String str = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainMenuActivity.EXTRA_GAMESIZE);

    String[] gameSizes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gamesizes);

    if(str.equals(gameSizes[0])) size = new Dimension(3,5);
    else if(str.equals(gameSizes[1])) size = new Dimension(4,7);
    else if(str.equals(gameSizes[2])) size = new Dimension(6,10);
    else
        throw new RuntimeException("Decoding game size from intent failed. String does not match.");

    return size;
}

private Bitmap loadBitmapFromIntent(){


    Bitmap selectedImage = null;
    /*try{
        InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imgUri);
        selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        Log.e("LOADING ERROR", "Cannot load picture from the URI given", ex);
    }*/
    try
    {
    Uri imgUri = (Uri) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(MainMenuActivity.EXTRA_IMGURI);
    //Opening the input stream and receiving Bitmap.
    InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imgUri); 

    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 2;

    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream,null,options);

    if (selectedImage.getHeight() > 1200)
        selectedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(selectedImage, selectedImage.getWidth() *1200 / selectedImage.getHeight(), 1200, false);
    System.gc();
    //return selectedImage;
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        Log.e("LOADING ERROR", "Cannot load picture from the URI given", ex);
    }
    /*
    if(selectedImage.getWidth()>selectedImage.getHeight()){
        selectedImage = BitmapOperator.rotateBitmap(selectedImage, 90);
    }*/
    return selectedImage;


}


@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class);
    //startActivity(intent);
    //showDialog(DIALOG_PAUSED_ID);
}

public Bitmap getPreview(String fileName) {
    File image = new File(fileName);

    BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath(), bounds);
    if ((bounds.outWidth == -1) || (bounds.outHeight == -1)) {
        return null;
    }
    int originalSize = (bounds.outHeight > bounds.outWidth) ? bounds.outHeight
            : bounds.outWidth;
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inSampleSize = originalSize / 64;
    // opts.inSampleSize = originalSize;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath());
}

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

  public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth,
       int reqHeight) { // BEST QUALITY MATCH

      // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
      final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
      options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
      BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

      // Calculate inSampleSize, Raw height and width of image
      final int height = options.outHeight;
      final int width = options.outWidth;
      options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
      int inSampleSize = 1;

      if (height > reqHeight) {
       inSampleSize = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
      }
      int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

      if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
       // if(Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth) > inSampleSize) //
       // If bigger SampSize..
       inSampleSize = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
      }

      options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

      // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
      options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

      return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
     }


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //showDialog(DIALOG_PAUSED_ID);
    super.onBackPressed();
}

public void inGameButtonsOnClick(View view){
    switch(view.getId()){

    case R.id.previewButton:
        inGameViewSwitcher.showNext();
        break;

    case R.id.backToGameButton:
        inGameViewSwitcher.showPrevious();
        break;
    }
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    System.gc();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    System.gc();
}

protected void onDestroy()
  {
    super.onDestroy();
    System.gc();
  }
}
```

Please help :(

Comment: Where does the crash occur? Have you tried running this under a debugger?

Comment: Sorry about my bad english, error occur when i choose a mode at second time( eg : choose "Easy" mode at start, then go back to previous activity/mode choose activity, then choose "Medium" mode), when i choose the mode at first time it doesnt crash, but in 2nd time, it crashes. this only happens when i add this line -(StartAppSDK.init(this, "209057502", true); ) next to super.onCreate